# Issues Renaming PC with WMIC in batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm using an IF statement to check if a computer might be domain joined before attempting to change the name of the computer. I have 2 blocks of code.

This block never has an issue on any Windows 7 or newer. But offers no checks before renaming.

```
    @echo off
    set /P "UserInput=Enter New Computer Name: "
    wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" call Rename name="%UserInput%"
    pause
```

But this block of code always exits in Error

```
    @echo off
    IF \\%computername%==%logonserver% (
        echo \\%computername% == %logonserver%
        set /P "UserInput=Enter New Computer Name: "
        pause
        wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" call Rename name="%UserInput%"
        pause
    ) ELSE (
        echo This computer may be DomainJoined contact your System Administrator
        pause
    )
```

The echo after comparison in the IF was strictly so I could verify the output. It was intended for debugging and added for clarity. This is the actual code with nothing omitted.

The Error is

> ERROR:
>
> Description = Invalid method Parameter(s)

If I force the comparison to fail. The `ELSE` statement runs. I don't believe the error is in the `IF/ELSE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove the need to delay variable expansion, *which is your issue*, you could remove the need to include that portion of the code inside an `If` block:

```bat
@Echo Off
If /I Not "\\%COMPUTERNAME%"=="%logonserver%" (
    Echo This computer may be DomainJoined; contact your System Administrator
    Pause
    Exit /B
)
Set /P "UserInput=Enter a new name for this computer: "
Pause
WMIC ComputerSystem Where "Not Name='%UserInput%'" Call Rename "Name='%UserInput%'"
Pause
```

You could also consider removing the `If` block completely by including an additional `Where` filter:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set /P "UserInput=Enter a new name for this computer: "
Pause
WMIC ComputerSystem Where "Not Name='%UserInput%' And Not Name='%logonserver:~2%'" Call Rename "Name='%UserInput%'"
Pause
```

The end user is free to type nothing or anything they wish; I would strongly advise that you perform some sort of validation on that input before considering renaming the system. *Most certainly with respect to allowed naming conventions, disallowed characters, and even rude or offensive strings.*